# Want double storage with two water tanks connected on direct water

Tags: connectors

[image]In our locality water supply is from 5am to 9pm and 6pm to 9pm twice a day.

During this duration we want to fill up both tanks with direct water supply having floating auto water cut on both.

Top water Tank placed at top 5th floor is 500 liters

Other one is 200 liters kept at first floor.

I want 200 liter to fill up auto matically from 500L when empty.

I want to know if this is possible?

Adding and image to clear the thing

Answer (score 2):

Sounds possible.  You don't likely need the connection from water supply to the 200L tank given the 500L tank is connecting to it.

You might try a setup with the Hydrocheck 6000 electric float switch instead of something mechanical.  Then setup an electric solonoid valve on the water supply that closes when the electric float reaches the top level.

I'd install a flood stop water supply solonoid as well near any place where the 500L tank might overflow so if the cut off doesn't work you don't flood out your house.

Comment: One limitation, sometimes due to low-pressure water does not reach the 500L tank. That's why direct line to each tank is required.

Comment: @CodeSpy install a pump to ensure that the water makes it uphill. This way, you only need one cut-off at the 500l tank. You fill it, it automatically fills the 200l tank and the pipe between them, then cuts off when it's full. Otherwise, you have to have cutoffs on both tanks and have 2 points of failure.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that as you drew it, because the 500L tank will overflow when there IS enough pressure to fill it, since you are connecting its outflow to the incoming water line. It would also drain back into the supply line when supply line pressure went away, rather than only filling your 200l tank.

Simple mechanical approach 1: float valve connects to incoming water line on each tank. Additional, separate, float valve on 200l connects 500l to 200l. I consider this one preferable. 3 valves, fewer failure modes.

Simple mechanical approach 2: float valve connects to incoming water line on each tank. Check valves are required to prevent your 500l tank from backfeeding the water line, and to prevent your 500l tank from being fed from its outflow when the waterline is on (so basically your diagram, but with with 2 check valves added.) 4 valves, some additional failure modes.

In any location with water supply this sporadic, I don't see making the water control system "electronic-ified" as likely to be a plus. If the water is on but the power is out, the mechanical float valve system works.

Provide overflow pipes leading to safe drainage locations (noticeable, not un-noticeable, safe locations) in the event of a mechanical valve failure. You want them noticeable so that you can correct the mechanical failure rather than wasting a lot of water. You'd want the same thing for an electric solenoid valve arrangement, regardless of any other controls, because electronic valves can also mechanically or electrically fail.

Comment: Good point on the passive overflow.